# How to Dict merge a map and a list with Map? (Dict is deprecated)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So in my phoenix app I have this warning:

> warning: Dict.merge/2 is deprecated, use the Map module for working
>   with maps or the Keyword module for working with keyword lists
>   test/support/test_helpers.ex:6

```
changes = Dict.merge(%{
  name: "Some User",
  username: "user#{Base.encode16(:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(8))}",
  password: "supersecret",
}, attrs)
```

And when I change it to `Map.merge` it crashes because attrs is not a map and it expects a map:

> ```
>  ** (BadMapError) expected a map, got: [username: "max"]
>  stacktrace:
>    (stdlib) :maps.merge(%{name: "Some User", password: "supersecret", username: "user19DA79B623406098"}, [username: "max"])
> ```

Is there any other method to make it work? or do I have to cast attrs into a map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enum.into/2` to merge two Enumerables. If you want a Keyword List as the result, the Keyword List should be the second argument, and if you want a Map as the result, the Map should be the second argument. I'm guessing you want a Map here, which means you can do:

```
changes = Enum.into(attrs, %{
  name: "Some User",
  username: "user#{Base.encode16(:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(8))}",
  password: "supersecret",
})
```

```
iex(1)> Enum.into(%{a: 1}, [b: 2])
[b: 2, a: 1]
iex(2)> Enum.into([b: 2], %{a: 1})
%{a: 1, b: 2}
```